# Unable to find the relevant tensor remote_handle: Op ID: 14738, Output num: 0

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets, tpu, data-pipeline

I am using a colab pro TPU instance for the purpose of patch image classification.
i'm using tensorflow version 2.3.0.

When calling model.fit I get the following error:  `InvalidArgumentError: Unable to find the relevant tensor remote_handle: Op ID: 14738, Output num: 0` with the following trace:

```
--------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-5fd2ec1ce2f9> in <module>()
     15         steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
     16         validation_data=dev_ds,
---> 17         validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS
     18     )

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1084       data_handler._initial_epoch = (  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1085           self._maybe_load_initial_epoch_from_ckpt(initial_epoch))
-> 1086       for epoch, iterator in data_handler.enumerate_epochs():
   1087         self.reset_metrics()
   1088         callbacks.on_epoch_begin(epoch)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in enumerate_epochs(self)
   1140         if self._insufficient_data:  # Set by `catch_stop_iteration`.
   1141           break
-> 1142         if self._adapter.should_recreate_iterator():
   1143           data_iterator = iter(self._dataset)
   1144         yield epoch, data_iterator

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in should_recreate_iterator(self)
    725     # each epoch.
    726     return (self._user_steps is None or
--> 727             cardinality.cardinality(self._dataset).numpy() == self._user_steps)
    728 
    729   def _validate_args(self, y, sample_weights, steps):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in numpy(self)
   1061     """
   1062     # TODO(slebedev): Consider avoiding a copy for non-CPU or remote tensors.
-> 1063     maybe_arr = self._numpy()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1064     return maybe_arr.copy() if isinstance(maybe_arr, np.ndarray) else maybe_arr
   1065 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _numpy(self)
   1029       return self._numpy_internal()
   1030     except core._NotOkStatusException as e:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1031       six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1032 
   1033   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Unable to find the relevant tensor remote_handle: Op ID: 14738, Output num: 0
```

H have two dataset zip files containing 300,000> and 100,000< training and validation examples which I download from my Google Drive using !gdown and unzip it on Colab VM. For data pipeline I use tf.data.Dataset API and feed the API with list of filepaths and then use .map method to perform image fetching from memory, **please keep in mind that my training dataset can't be fit into memory**

Here is the code for creating Dataset:

```
train_dir = '/content/content/Data/train'
dev_dir = '/content/content/Data/dev'

def create_dataset(dir, label_dic, is_training=True):
    filepaths = list(tf.data.Dataset.list_files(dir + '/*.jpg'))

    labels = []

    for f in filepaths:
        ind = f.numpy().decode().split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
        labels.append(label_dic[ind])

    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filepaths, labels))
    ds = ds.map(load_images, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    ds = ds.cache() 

    if is_training:
        ds = ds.shuffle(len(filepaths), reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
        ds = ds.repeat(EPOCHS) 
    ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE) 
    ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    return ds


train_ds = create_dataset(train_dir, train_label)
dev_ds = create_dataset(dev_dir, dev_label, False)
```

And here is the code for creating and compiling my model and fitting the datasets, I use a keras custom model with VGG16 backend:

```
def create_model(input_shape, batch_size):
    VGG16 = keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=False,input_shape=input_shape, weights='imagenet')

    for layer in VGG16.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    input_layer = keras.Input(shape=input_shape, batch_size=batch_size)

    VGG_out = VGG16(input_layer)

    x = Flatten(name='flatten', input_shape=(512,8,8))(VGG_out)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='fc2')(x)

    model = Model(input_layer, x)
    model.summary()
    return model

with strategy.scope():

    model = create_model(INPUT_SHAPE, BATCH_SIZE)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            metrics=['accuracy'])
    
model.fit(train_ds,
        epochs=5,
        steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
        validation_data=dev_ds,
        validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS
    )
```

**For TPU initialization and strategy**I use a `strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)`
Initialization code shown below:

```
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)

tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))
```

a copy of the whole notebook with outputs can be reached at: [Colab Ipython Notebook](https://github.com/Pooya448/Tumor_Segmentation/blob/main/Patch_Classification.ipynb)

Comment: i'm running into the same issue when training on a TPU but only if I have num_epochs > 1. Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @Pooya448
Did the above error resolved?

Answer (score 1):

@Pooya448

I know this is quite late, but this may be useful for anyone stuck here.
Following is the function I use to connect to TPUs.

```py
def connect_to_tpu(tpu_address: str = None):
    if tpu_address is not None:  # When using GCP
        cluster_resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(
            tpu=tpu_address)
        if tpu_address not in ("", "local"):
            tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(cluster_resolver)
        tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(cluster_resolver)
        strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(cluster_resolver)
        print("Running on TPU ", cluster_resolver.master())
        print("REPLICAS: ", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
        return cluster_resolver, strategy
    else:                           # When using Colab or Kaggle
        try:
            cluster_resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver.connect()
            strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(cluster_resolver)
            print("Running on TPU ", cluster_resolver.master())
            print("REPLICAS: ", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
            return cluster_resolver, strategy
        except:
            print("WARNING: No TPU detected.")
            mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
            return None, mirrored_strategy
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried all the methods that are suggested in git and stackoverflow none of them worked for me. But what worked is I created a new notebook and connected it to the TPU and trained the model. It worked fine, so may be this is related to the problem of the notebook at the time when we created it.